# TexStudio - my citations show up with weird characters

Tags: latex, texstudio

When I try to cite a reference with `\cite` all my references is shown with weird characters. I am using the latest release of TexStudio 4.0.1.

[image]

Comment: Can you show one sample .bib entry and also tell us which encoding you use for your tex and bib file?

Comment: I reinstalled TexStudio and after that everything worked perfectly ok again!